# react-snap appends routes (vue-router)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, react-snap

I am using router-links on my pages. After implementing react-snap, those stopped working correctly, routes are appended. I looked into the generated HTML and everything is fine there.

Take a look at the green buttons on https://static.lernzettel.org/metrum/ - when accessing the page via this link, the links are not working correctly - however, when navigating there from the homepage everything is fine.

https://lernzettel.org/metrum is the version without using react-snap - no issues there in either case.
I hope this is good enough for a demo. The relevant code is:

```
<v-card :to="{ path: post.meta.previous_post.slug}"></v-card>
```

post.meta.previous_post.slug in this case is "/kadenz" | I am using vuetify, should be rendered as a normal router-link | The router is in history mode.

Do you have any idea on how to deal with this?

Thanks for any help in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

post.meta.previous_post.slug was missing the / - argggh, all working fine now:)